# I'm trying to install taipy but I keep getting an error. How do I rectify it?

Tags: installation, cmake, pyarrow, windows-11, taipy

I just typed:

pip install taipy

[ss of command promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sn5i.png)

I already had python installed. I tried to install mingw, cmake and Microsoft Visual build tools but the same error persists. I'm not sure what else to do or how to debug as I'm a complete beginner. What can I do to rectify it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the **error message** to be in the **question post** itself, as **text**, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question post accordingly.

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/Avaiga/taipy/issues/627) has been created and is taken care of at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

taipy pins pyarrow==12 and you are using python 3.12 for which there are no wheels for pyarrow. Building pyarrow from source is non-trivial and should be avoided for normal use. Please see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77377847/19933286) for details.